# How Can I Get touch events in an iPad App's hidden status bar's area?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, statusbar

I read about this problem for the iPhone on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146164/how-can-i-get-touch-events-in-an-iphone-apps-hidden-status-bars-area).

The post says it's only a simulator problem. Right now I've got the same problem on my iPad app, on the device itself. The app has a status bar - but after hiding it in app i can't click/touch in that area (using iOS version 4.2).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're desperate enough, you could have your own window on top of the (invisible) status bar and process events in there. Set its windowLevel high enough and you're good to go. However, that might not be a good solution for you, because there's no way to forward touches from one window to another. You might end up having to do a lot of touch handling yourself.