# Hidden status bar intercepts touchs on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, statusbar

In my app I'm using UI for several first screens, and then switch to OpenGL view controller (cocos3d). I show status bar for UI view controllers, and then hide it before switching to OpenGL.

The strange thing is, that while running the app on iPhone all is good, but on iPad the hidden status bar starts to intercept all touches within its bounding box.

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471482/how-can-i-get-touch-events-in-an-ipad-apps-hidden-status-bars-area), which refers to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146164/how-can-i-get-touch-events-in-an-iphone-apps-hidden-status-bars-area). There seems to be a bug of Simulator with the same behavior, but I encounter this on real devices (both iPhone and iPad are real devices).

I'm creating OpenGL view controller programmatically **without** differentiating like

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```

In my `.plist`I have:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

To hide status bar I'm using:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
```

Also, I'm targeting iOS 7.

I've almost got crazy about this, does someone encountered the same issue? How can I allow touches for status bar area?

Comment: I am struggling with this problem as well, any solutions?

Comment: @Lope as far as I remember - I did not find the solution, and released the app with this problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this in the .m of the viewcontroller

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: that does not help, since `View controller-based status bar` is set to `NO` :(